# Disable textbox while process running in button click event

Tags: c#, button, textbox

I want to disable a `textbox` while processes are running in a button click event.
I noticed that the `textbox` gets disabled after the event while the `radiobuttons` in the `groupbox` gets disabled immediately.
The button should be disabled at the start and depending on the return values of somemethods it should get back enabled or stays disabled.

Thats my current code:

```
private async void BtnConfirmClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        textbox.Enabled = false;
        groupbox.Enabled = false;
        await somemethod()
         ... 
    }
}
```

I've the same problem when changing the text while in the button event.

Comment: It depends of what `somemethod` does synchronously on the UI thread.

Comment: there're several 'async' methods, some change configfiles, some import certificates,... I want the textbox to be disabled at the start of the button click event like the groupbox behaves.

Comment: It should be disabled - only the visual appearance is not reflecting that if you block the UI thread. You can see that by adding `textbox.Update();` after `textbox.Enabled = false;`.

Comment: Yes of course, UI thread... No it works. Thanks a lot. Can I mark this comment as answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
private async void BtnConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // you dont want user to click twice
        BtnConfirm.Enabled = false;

        // ConfigureAwait(false) configures the task so it doesn't need to block caller thread
        await Somemethod().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    finally
    {
        // BeginInvoke prevents thread access exceptions
        BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
        {
            BtnConfirm.Enabled = true;
        });
    }
}

private async Task Somemethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
}
```

There it is. Be sure to do any UI manipulations in BeginInvoke after ConfigureAwait(false) because task is probably going to end up on another thread.
Hope it helps.